# Did the length of a Discord token recently change?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, discord.net, discord-jda

My Discord authorization token is 70 characters long, it goes as follows:

```
OTk1MTU1NzcyMzYxMTQ2NDM4.[6 characters].[38 characters]
```

But every token I see online is 59 characters long. Even the token grabbers only get the first 59 characters of my token. The regex everyone seem to use to know whether a string could be a token ( not MFA ) is `/[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{27}/` which clearly implies that there are 59 characters ( 57 + 2 periods ). Did the length of a token recently change?

PS: I successfully managed to make requests to the Discord API using it, it's valid.

Comment: I can confirm what you are seeing, my old tokens are all 59 characters and when I regenerate a new one it is 70 characters long. It seeems like a silent change since I could not find anything regarding it in the official change log: https://discord.com/developers/docs/change-log

Comment: @moinierer3000 Alright, so that confirms what I thought, thank you. Also, do you know if the length of a token with MFA enabled changed?

Comment: I have MFA on my account enabled so I would say yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the length of the discord tokens has changes over the time because of the decoded timestamp in the Base64 format in the token.

The Token is an encoded text as Text and the first letters are giving informations about the registration date of the user / bot.

example:
if I decode the token beginning I get the ID of the object.
In your case the ID of the bot would be `995155772361146438`.

That's why it's changing.

Comment: That makes sense, are all the tokens either 59/70 characters long or some of them might be an other length?

Comment: @Redy a bot ID is a snowflake, so that means it can vary in length. Discord's snowflake length recently went from 18 characters to 19, and it will stay on that until the year 2083. That means you can pretty much always expect them to be between 17 and 19 characters in length.